# va_arg gives garbage text

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I made a simple test case:

```
static void va_test(char* str_arg, ...)
{ 
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, str_arg); 
  for( ; ; ) { 
    if (str_arg == NULL)
      break; 
    int n = va_arg(ap,int);
    printf("arg: %s,%d\n", str_arg, n);
    str_arg = va_arg(ap,char*);
  }
  va_end(ap);
  printf("\n");
}
```

When I run it with `va_test("beer",1,"cofe",2,"juice",3,0)` in a standalone executable it works fine. But when I call it from my project executable, which is very big, it gives some garbage string like this:

```
arg: bear,1
arg: cofe,2
arg: juice,3
arg: ^X(garbage...),57
```

I guess there must be a memory chaos happened before I call this function, but how can I debug it?

**[EDIT]**
I updated the description a little, since strictly speaking, the bug happens when I passed more than 6 args to va_test. I realized that the first six 64bits args are passed by register in amd64 machine, while other args are passed by stack. The problem happens when va_arg tries to get the first arg from `*overflow_arg_area`.

Comment: But you can still debug the big app? Is it 64-bit unlike the simple test case? Code looks good unless for some reason `0` argument is truncated to "less than pointer size".

Comment: I forgot to mention that the bug doesn't show up if I compile my big app with gcc debug option...:$

Comment: @solotim, this can have multiple reasons. One here might just be that when compiling for debugging your call will never be inlined. Otherwise it might since you have declared your function `static`. So a debug version and a "normal" version will find quite different values on the stack. In particular for the debug version you might be lucky of having more `0`s where your argument is pointing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation that is most likely to me is that you are on a system where the `int` 0 has a differeent representation than the `char *` 0. This can be on a 64 bit system where `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(char *) == 8`.

Try to pass the last argument as `(char *) 0` instead of `0`, and you should be fine. All the rest of the code looks technically correct.

Comment: +1, yes, this is one of the major pitfalls of the va_arg concept.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the root cause. I tried as you suggested but failed too. Besides, if it's the culprit, why my standalone exe works. The trigger condition for this bug must be something else, but I'm running out of means to debug it...

Comment: @solotim Does that mean you are compiling your app as 32 bit, on a common non-esoteric platform ? If so, start looking for memory errors (buffer overflows in particular), missing prototypes, strange project setting e.g. regarding calling conventions, or if your real code indeed does pass the expected arguments around in pairs of int,char* , ending with a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If using GCC, you could declare your `va_test` with `__attribute__((sentinel))` and ensure that every call occurrence is null-terminated with e.g.

```
 #define va_test(Fmt,...) va_test(Fmt,__VA_ARGS__,NULL)
```

I guess your memory chaos is because some call is not null terminated.

Comment: if you put it in a macro like that, better put the correct value as a sentinel, which is `(char*)0`. `NULL` must not necessarily be of pointer type, you should never use it in a va_arg context.

Comment: Are you sure that NULL is not a pointer? On my Linux/Debian `<stddef.h>` is `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/stddef.h` and contains `#define NULL ((void *)0)` (but NULL is 0 for C++).

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure, I read the standard :) It only is defined to be a "null pointer constant". A null pointer constant can be any constant expression that evaluates to `0`, e.g `0`, `'\0'`, an enumeration constant of value `0`, or something like `(void*)0`. Have a look at http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/dont-use-null/ for the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux manual page for `va_arg`:

```
If there is no next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the
actual next  argument  (aspromoted according to the default argument promotions),
random errors will occur.
```

You have to find another way of ending the loop, you can not trust the result of `va_arg` once you fetched all argument.

The random values you are getting is simply what's on the stack after the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Starynkevitch and Pileborg, it might also be a good idea to replace the for loop with a while for better readability.

```
while (str_arg != NULL) {
   /* Do stuff */
}
```

(But replace `str_arg != NULL` with your new end condition.) [Edit: Thank you Jens.]

Comment: only that it is `!=` and not `==`

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where the C standard is not very explicit. It can be problematic where variadic functions are null-terminated. For implementations where `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0`, a pointer is passed as an argument and therefore a pointer must be read using `va_arg` to avoid undefined behaviour. If `NULL` is defined as just `0` (which is permitted by the C standard but in my own personal experience is not a popular definition), then an `int` is passed as an argument, and therefore an `int` must be read using `va_arg` to avoid undefined behaviour. `int` and `void *` are two fundamentally different types that often have different sizes, so it can cause real issues.

If your C implementation defines `NULL` as `(void *)0`, make sure to provide `NULL` in your function call instead of just `0`. If you want your code to be as portable as possible, I would avoid passing `0` or `NULL` and instead maybe provide an empty string as the terminator, or something like that.

Comment: just using `(char*)0` as a sentinel should be portable and always be correct

Comment: @JensGustedt `(void *)0` is also correct but I think it looks ugly, and masking it behind a macro or variable adds kludge and makes the code less understandable without context.:

Comment: sure `(void*)0` would also do it. But I'd prefer `(char*)0` since this is explicitly the type that the function expects. And to my opinion all this shows that the default promotion rules in combination with va_args (and this is the only place where you find them still) are just flawed. va_arg function should only be used by the C library itself.